# Best practice with Pandas to calculate differences between dates according to categories

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sort differences between values grouped by dates and categories in a Pandas DataFrame. At the end, what matters is the name of the categories with the lowest and highest increases between the two dates, and the corresponding increases.

I think my code works, but it looks over complicated. I would like to find the best Pandas way (fastest, most standard, most straight forward, etc.) to do it. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creation of random data
size = 1_000
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Borough'] = np.random.choice(['Brooklyn', 'Manhattan', 'Bronx', 'Queens', 'Staten Island'], size)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(2011, 2021, size), format="%Y")
df['Nbr_permits'] = np.random.randint(0, 300, size)

# Calculation of the sorted differences in the number of permits per boroughs between 2011 and 2020
res = (df[(df['Date'].dt.year == 2020)].groupby('Borough')['Nbr_permits'].sum() - df[(df['Date'].dt.year == 2011)].groupby('Borough')['Nbr_permits'].sum()).sort_values().dropna()

#Lowest progression of nbr_permits between 2011 and 2020:
print(res.idxmin(), res[res.idxmin()])

#Highest progression of nbr_permits between 2011 and 2020:
print(res.idxmax(), res[res.idxmax()])
```

Can I do better with Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way

```
# extract year from Date column
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year

# Reshape into wide format and agg 
# to sum permits per Borough and Year
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Borough', 
                     columns='Year', 
                     values='Nbr_permits', 
                     aggfunc='sum')

# Calculate the diff
diff = df1[2020] - df1[2011]
diff[[diff.idxmin(), diff.idxmax()]]
```

Result

```
Borough
Queens     -1236
Brooklyn    2097
dtype: int64
```